# ¿Cómo hacer carousel y que las imagenes tengan height estandar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css, bootstrap

Saludos, tengo un pequeño problema, estoy tratando de hacer un carousel con Bootstrap y Jquery, todo bien allí, el problema que tengo es que si las imagenes tienen height diferente hace que se alteren los demas contenidos(navbar, jumbotron). Al cambiar la imagen del slide con la fechita, si la imagen tiene mas resolucion, hace que crezca el carousel. lo que quiero es que el carrousel tenga height estandar(fijo por asi decirlo), que no se haga mas grande sin importar el tamaño de la imagen.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
  $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 900, function() {

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".slideanim").each(function() {
      var pos = $(this).offset().top;

      var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (pos < winTop + 600) {
        $(this).addClass("slide");
      }
    });
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 400 15px Lato, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #818181;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>img,
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color: #1B2F95;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 100px 25px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 60px 50px;
}

.bg-grey {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.logo-small {
  color: #f4511e;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.logo {
  color: #f4511e;
  font-size: 200px;
}

.thumbnail {
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.carousel-control.right,
.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: none;
  color: #f4511e;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  border-color: #f4511e;
}

.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: #f4511e;
}

.item h4 {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 70px 0;
}

.item span {
  font-style: normal;
}

.panel {
  border: 1px solid #f4511e;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}

.panel:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.panel-footer .btn:hover {
  border: 1px solid #f4511e;
  background-color: #fff !important;
  color: #f4511e;
}

.panel-heading {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #f4511e !important;
  padding: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.panel-footer {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.panel-footer h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.panel-footer h4 {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.panel-footer .btn {
  margin: 15px 0;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #1B2F95;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover,
.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #f4511e !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff !important;
}

footer .glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #f4511e;
}

.slideanim {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slide {
  animation-name: slide;
  -webkit-animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px 0;
  }
  .btn-lg {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .logo {
    font-size: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x600/02809E/18D18F" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x500/3498db/2980b9" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Repacar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Company</h1>
  <p>We specialize in blablabla</p>
  <form>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address" required>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Subscribe</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<!-- Container (About Section) -->
<div id="about" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h2>About Company Page</h2><br>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4><br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <br><button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Get in Touch</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal logo"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid bg-grey">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe logo slideanim"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h2>Our Values</h2><br>
      <h4><strong>MISSION:</strong> Our mission lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat.</h4><br>
      <p><strong>VISION:</strong> Our vision Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Container (Services Section) -->
<div id="services" class="container-fluid text-center">
  <h2>SERVICES</h2>
  <h4>What we offer</h4>
  <br>
  <div class="row slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off logo-small"></span>
      <h4>POWER</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart logo-small"></span>
      <h4>LOVE</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock logo-small"></span>
      <h4>JOB DONE</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <div class="row slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf logo-small"></span>
      <h4>GREEN</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate logo-small"></span>
      <h4>CERTIFIED</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench logo-small"></span>
      <h4 style="color:#303030;">HARD WORK</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Container (Portfolio Section) -->
<div id="portfolio" class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
  <h2>Portfolio</h2><br>
  <h4>What we have created</h4>
  <div class="row text-center slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/03.jpg" alt="Paris" width="400" height="300">
        <p><strong>Paris</strong></p>
        <p>Yes, we built Paris</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/03.jpg" alt="New York" width="400" height="300">
        <p><strong>New York</strong></p>
        <p>We built New York</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/03.jpg" alt="San Francisco" width="400" height="300">
        <p><strong>San Francisco</strong></p>
        <p>Yes, San Fran is ours</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><br>

  <h2>What our customers say</h2>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide text-center" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <h4>"This company is the best. I am so happy with the result!"<br><span>Michael Roe, Vice President, Comment Box</span></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h4>"One word... WOW!!"<br><span>John Doe, Salesman, Rep Inc</span></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h4>"Could I... BE any more happy with this company?"<br><span>Chandler Bing, Actor, FriendsAlot</span></h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Container (Pricing Section) -->
<div id="pricing" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h2>Pricing</h2>
    <h4>Choose a payment plan that works for you</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="row slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1>Basic</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p><strong>20</strong> Lorem</p>
          <p><strong>15</strong> Ipsum</p>
          <p><strong>5</strong> Dolor</p>
          <p><strong>2</strong> Sit</p>
          <p><strong>Endless</strong> Amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <h3>$19</h3>
          <h4>per month</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1>Pro</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p><strong>50</strong> Lorem</p>
          <p><strong>25</strong> Ipsum</p>
          <p><strong>10</strong> Dolor</p>
          <p><strong>5</strong> Sit</p>
          <p><strong>Endless</strong> Amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <h3>$29</h3>
          <h4>per month</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1>Premium</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p><strong>100</strong> Lorem</p>
          <p><strong>50</strong> Ipsum</p>
          <p><strong>25</strong> Dolor</p>
          <p><strong>10</strong> Sit</p>
          <p><strong>Endless</strong> Amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <h3>$49</h3>
          <h4>per month</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Container (Contact Section) -->
<div id="contact" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
  <h2 class="text-center">CONTACT</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <p>Contact us and we'll get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Chicago, US</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> +00 1515151515</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> myemail@something.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero puedan ver lo que quiero hacer y me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clave esta en este fragmento del css:

```
.carousel-inner>.item>img,
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
    height: 150px !important;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

donde `height: 150px !important;` es para poner la altura que tu carousel necesita y `width: auto;` es para evitar que las imagenes se deformen

```css
body {
  font: 400 15px Lato, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #818181;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  color: #303030;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>img,
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
  height: 150px !important;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-color: #1B2F95;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 100px 25px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 60px 50px;
}

.bg-grey {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.logo-small {
  color: #f4511e;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.logo {
  color: #f4511e;
  font-size: 200px;
}

.thumbnail {
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.carousel-control.right,
.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: none;
  color: #f4511e;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  border-color: #f4511e;
}

.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: #f4511e;
}

.item h4 {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.375em;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 70px 0;
}

.item span {
  font-style: normal;
}

.panel {
  border: 1px solid #f4511e;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}

.panel:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.panel-footer .btn:hover {
  border: 1px solid #f4511e;
  background-color: #fff !important;
  color: #f4511e;
}

.panel-heading {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #f4511e !important;
  padding: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.panel-footer {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.panel-footer h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.panel-footer h4 {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.panel-footer .btn {
  margin: 15px 0;
  background-color: #f4511e;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #1B2F95;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover,
.navbar-nav li.active a {
  color: #f4511e !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff !important;
}

footer .glyphicon {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #f4511e;
}

.slideanim {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slide {
  animation-name: slide;
  -webkit-animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-4 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 25px 0;
  }
  .btn-lg {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .logo {
    font-size: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <br><br><br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1920x600/02809E/18D18F" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x500/3498db/2980b9" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x260" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beautiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">Repacar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Company</h1>
  <p>We specialize in blablabla</p>
  <form>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" size="50" placeholder="Email Address" required>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Subscribe</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<!-- Container (About Section) -->
<div id="about" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h2>About Company Page</h2><br>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</h4><br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <br><button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Get in Touch</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-signal logo"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- Container (Portfolio Section) -->
<div id="portfolio" class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
  <h2>Portfolio</h2><br>
  <h4>What we have created</h4>
  <div class="row text-center slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/03.jpg" alt="Paris" width="400" height="300">
        <p><strong>Paris</strong></p>
        <p>Yes, we built Paris</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/03.jpg" alt="New York" width="400" height="300">
        <p><strong>New York</strong></p>
        <p>We built New York</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/03.jpg" alt="San Francisco" width="400" height="300">
        <p><strong>San Francisco</strong></p>
        <p>Yes, San Fran is ours</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><br>

  <h2>What our customers say</h2>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide text-center" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <h4>"This company is the best. I am so happy with the result!"<br><span>Michael Roe, Vice President, Comment Box</span></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h4>"One word... WOW!!"<br><span>John Doe, Salesman, Rep Inc</span></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <h4>"Could I... BE any more happy with this company?"<br><span>Chandler Bing, Actor, FriendsAlot</span></h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Container (Pricing Section) -->
<div id="pricing" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h2>Pricing</h2>
    <h4>Choose a payment plan that works for you</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="row slideanim">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1>Basic</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p><strong>20</strong> Lorem</p>
          <p><strong>15</strong> Ipsum</p>
          <p><strong>5</strong> Dolor</p>
          <p><strong>2</strong> Sit</p>
          <p><strong>Endless</strong> Amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <h3>$19</h3>
          <h4>per month</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1>Pro</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p><strong>50</strong> Lorem</p>
          <p><strong>25</strong> Ipsum</p>
          <p><strong>10</strong> Dolor</p>
          <p><strong>5</strong> Sit</p>
          <p><strong>Endless</strong> Amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <h3>$29</h3>
          <h4>per month</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1>Premium</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <p><strong>100</strong> Lorem</p>
          <p><strong>50</strong> Ipsum</p>
          <p><strong>25</strong> Dolor</p>
          <p><strong>10</strong> Sit</p>
          <p><strong>Endless</strong> Amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <h3>$49</h3>
          <h4>per month</h4>
          <button class="btn btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Container (Contact Section) -->
<div id="contact" class="container-fluid bg-grey">
  <h2 class="text-center">CONTACT</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <p>Contact us and we'll get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Chicago, US</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> +00 1515151515</p>
      <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> myemail@something.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 slideanim">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Comment" rows="5"></textarea><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para ajustarlo al ancho del div y además que tenga siempre un tamaño constante recomiendo poner la imagen como background del div de esta forma:

```
<div
   class="item"
   style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/150x150');">
   .......
</div>
```

Adjunto un [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reneson/h6hsxvht/) donde se puede ver de mejor forma.

Comment: gracias, ahora tengo una duda y quiza puedas ayudarme, hay forma de desplegar la imagen en todo el contenedor?

Comment: ¿a que te refieres con desplegarlo? No me queda claro

Comment: Osea, por asi decirlo que se despliegue la imagen del carousel hasta por debajo de la flecha que sirve para cambirar a la siguiente imagen @rene-limon

Comment: @LuisFernando edité mi respuesta con un fiddle, no lo agregué aquí porque excedí el limite de caracteres en la respuesta.

Comment: Muy util, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega en el `css` una clase `.item img`:

```
.item img{
    max-height:150px;
}
```

Si hay conflicto con otro `css` ponle `!important`

```
.item img{
    max-height:150px !important;
}
```